# Option to wait until upload activity is getting completed using UI Path

Tags: rpa, uipath

I am trying to automate a web page where I need to upload 1GB large file and then I need to sign out and close the browser but when file upload is happening am getting logged out and browser get closed. 
How can I wait until particular upload action is completed and captured the start and end time of upload activity?
Request to please assist

Comment: Could you show how far you came already. And which web page you mean? Give some examples we can work on. This makes you question more unstandable.

Answer (score 2):

With the limited information that is provided in the post, I believe the problem is with the large file size.
Since you're trying to upload a file of size more than a gigabyte , the website is throwing you out, maybe due to inactivity?

I would suggest the check the condition of the website and controls just before you're being logged out to verify if it's because of inactivity.

If it does turn out due to inactivity, then maybe you can perform some activity (clicks, changing controls state, etc) to prevent it from getting inactive.

If not, do share the details about the conditions right before you're logged out.
And as always, share the logs if you have any. That might help.